# Message Boxes Modal

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I've been working at this on and off for a while but essentially I have a class that I call to display message boxes.

I'm trying to get my message boxes to be modal, which is easily done if you specify the form to be modal to.

So my form is declared like this

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
```

and it is instantiated like this

```
var mainForm = new MainForm();
```

So I have a class that contains methods which open message boxes like this

```
MainForm.ActiveForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    MessageBox.Show(MainForm.ActiveForm, message, title, buttons, icon);
}));
```

This works fine, but active form only works when the form is active.....

Anyways is there an easy way around this?

Comment: "message boxes to be modal" these message boxes do they inherit from Windows.System.forms.form or are you talking about messagebox.show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution that works fairly well, but I'm not sure if there is a more elegant solution.

So in MainForm.cs I have

```
public static Form mainWindow { get; private set; }
```

Then in the OnLoad method

```
Focus();
BringToFront();
mainWindow = MainForm.ActiveForm;
```

Then in my message box method:

```
MainForm.mainWindow.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    MainForm.mainWindow.BringToFront();
    MessageBox.Show(MainForm.mainWindow, message, title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, icon);
}));
```

Am I missing something here? Is there a better alternative to mainWindow = MainForm.ActiveForm?

Comment: Another option is to set mainWindow = FindForm(); in the on load method.

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me:

```
MessageBox.Show(Form.ActiveForm,"Finished processing", "Process finished", , MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Form.ActiveForm would give you the currently active form, even if you are raising your MessageBox from any other class.

Answer (score 2):

I'm kind of a C# newbie, but aren't MessageBoxes already modal? And if you were making your own messagebox, couldn't you just do `messageboxform.ShowDialog();`?

Comment: Sadly, ShowDialog is a method for WPF windows not WinForms [MessageBoxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/411ze57x.aspx).

Comment: you can have a form.ShowDialog but not a messagebox in windows forms

Comment: @funseiki No, I'm pretty sure you can use .ShowDialog() in windows forms.

Comment: @MicahArmantrout He could make his own form that acted like a MessageBox, and then use .ShowDialog().

Comment: @MicahArmantrout and Jutanium you're right, it applies to both, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is avoid using that first parameter, the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx) has a few Show methods for a Winforms Messagebox.

You might try this one:

```
public static DialogResult Show(
    string text,
    string caption,
    MessageBoxButtons buttons,
    MessageBoxIcon icon,
    MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton
 )
```

So for you:

```
MessageBox.Show(message, title, buttons, icon);
```

Edit:
I believe this should appear modal (without that first parameter) because it's being invoked from the main form.

Comment: If you don't specify the first parameter, the message box is modal to the desktop.